# Помогите понять json в GO

Tags: json, golang

**При энкодинге выводит:** `{"Tables":{"Id":{"Column":{},"Row":{},"Border":{}}}}`

**А хочется**  (и в целом, каким должна быть структура для этого JSON?) **:**

```
{
"tables": {
    "table_001": {

        "dx":10.5, "dy": 10.5,

        "column": {
            "widths": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
            "align":[1,3,3],
            "colors": ["#1513","#1513","#1513"]
        },
        "row": {
            "heights": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
            "align": [3, null, null],
            "colors": ["#1513","#1513","#1513"]
        },
        "border": {
            "color": "#12244",
            "style": "solid", 
            "width": 1,
            "drawb": [                  
                        ["ltrb", "ltrb", "ltrb"],
                        ["ltrb", "ltrb", "ltrb"],
                        ["ltrb", "ltrb", "ltrb"]
                    ]
        },
        "tcont": [
                    ["рорпорп", "ID", "Year"],
                    ["ывывп", "1212", "2014"],
                    ["вапвапва", "1ht212", "2014"]
                ]
    }
}
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    type column struct {
        widths []float64
        align  []int32
        colors []string
    }
    type row struct {
        heights []float64
        align   []int32
        colors  []string
    }
    type border struct {
        width float64
        drawb [][]string
        color string
        style string
    }
    type table struct {
        dx     float64
        dy     float64
        Column column
        Row    row
        Border border
        tcont  [][]string
    }
    type tables struct {
        Id table
    }
    type jsonn struct {
        Tables tables 
    }

    var tle = jsonn{
        Tables: tables{
            Id: table{
                dx: 10.5, dy: 10.5,
                Column: column{
                    widths: []float64{70.0, 20.0, 20.0},
                    align:  []int32{1, 1, 1},
                    colors: []string{"", "", ""},
                },
                Row: row{
                    heights: []float64{40.0, 40.0, 40.0},
                    align:   []int32{1, 1, 1},
                    colors:  []string{"", "", ""},
                },
                Border: border{
                    width: 1.0,
                    drawb: [][]string{
                        {"ltrb", "ltrb", "ltrb"},
                        {"ltrb", "ltrb", "ltrb"},
                        {"ltrb", "ltrb", "ltrb"},
                    },
                    color: "#000000",
                    style: "solid",
                },
                tcont: [][]string{
                    {"polplpl", "ID", "Year"},
                    {"blablabla", "1212", "2014"},
                    {"blablabla", "1ht212", "2014"},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    b,err := json.Marshal(tle)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
}
```

Comment: Все, разобрался. Оказывается переменные в структуре долны начинаться с большой буквы

Answer (score 5):

Если поля структуры объявляются с прописной буквы, то они не экспортируемые, и как следствие им нельзя присвоить значение. Для того, чтобы работать с JSON в Go необходимо объявлять поля с заглавной буквы. Все поля в JSON, также должны начинаться с заглавной.