# Создание golang-структуры для JSON-документа

Tags: json, golang

Добрый день.

Есть такой входящий документ:

```
{
 "123":{"custname":"Foo","custemail":"foo@mail.ru"},
 "456":{"custname":"Bar","custemail":"bar@mail.ru"}
}
```

Пробую создать структуру для описания этого документа:

```
type CustItemJSON struct {
    Custname    string
    Custemail   string
}

type CustomersJSON struct {
    id []CustItemJSON
}
.....
var cj CustomersJSON
err: = json.Unmarshal(indoc, &cj)
fmt.Println(cj) // {[]}
```

И на выходе получаю пустоту. Помогите создать правильную конструкцию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите понять json в GO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/303008/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте мап:

```
type CustItemJSON struct {
    Custname  string `json:"custname"`
    Custemail string `json:"custemail"`
}

type CustJSON map[string]CustItemJSON
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/awQCCk51sI.

Comment: да. я уже так и поступил