# Создать структуру для XML

Tags: xml, golang, xmlparser

Проблема с созданием структуры из XML-файла (Я его превратил в слайс байт). После парсинга на выходе получаю nil-структуру List. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так со структурами? Или я ошибся в функции с парсингом?

```golang
package lists

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type List struct {
    Id           int    `xml:"Id"`
    Name         string `xml:"Name"`
    FriendlyName string `xml:"FriendlyName"`
    Language     string `xml:"Language"`
    OptInMode    string `xml:"OptInMode"`
}

type Lists struct {
    List []List `xml:"List"`
}

type Data struct {
    Lists []Lists `xml: "Lists"`
}

type ApiResponse struct {
    Xmlns  string `xml: "xmlns:xsd, attr"`
    Xmlns2 string `xml: "xmlns:xsi, attr"`
    Data   []Data `xml: "Data"`
}

var xmlData = []byte(
    `<ApiResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Data>
      <Lists>
       <List>
        <Id>2320</Id>
        <Name>SL_subscribers</Name>
        <Language>ru-RU</Language>
        <OptInMode>SingleOptIn</OptInMode>
      </List>
      <List>
        <Id>2425</Id>
        <Name>Обычный лист М</Name>
        <FriendlyName>Обычный лист М</FriendlyName>
        <Language>ru-RU</Language>
        <OptInMode>DoubleOptIn</OptInMode>
      </List>
     </Lists>
    </Data>
   </ApiResponse>`)

func CountStruct() {
    v := new(Lists)
    err := xml.Unmarshal(xmlData, &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(v.list)
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите понять json в GO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/303008/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-go)

Comment: @Ainar-G, Я исправил, но проблема осталась. Все таки проблема в структурах...

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде большое количество проблем. Во-первых, `v` должно быть типа `ApiResponse` (который [должен](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms) называться `APIResponse`; golint об этом предупреждает).

Во-вторых, в тэгах не допускаются пробелы после двоеточия. Вы бы заметили это, если бы использовали go vet.

В-третьих, вы неправильно используете пространства имён XML (хотя с ними вообще в го не очень). go vet тоже об этом предупреждает.

Вот рабочий код: https://play.golang.org/p/Qr7xRpGLsNL.