# json в структуру

Tags: javascript, json, golang

Отправляю json через js сокет, читаю сообщение на сервере go:

```
{"x":554,"y":236,"speed":"0","radius":"6","speedMax":"0","acceleration":"0","friction":"0.00","color":"#ffffff","border":"#000000","widthBorder":"3"}
```

пытаюсь преобразовать в структуру:

```
p := &Point{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &p)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("err json:", err)
}
log.Println(p)
```

Выводит:

```
 &{0 0 0 0 0 0 0   }
```

Собственно что я делаю не так? Ошбибок некаких не выводит.

Вот структура:

```
type Point struct {
    x            float64 `json:"x"`
    y            float64 `json:"y"`
    speed        float64 `json:"speed"`
    speedMax     float64 `json:"speedMax"`
    acceleration float64 `json:"acceleration"`
    radius       float64 `json:"radius"`
    friction     float64 `json:"friction"`
    color        string  `json:"color"`
    border       string  `json:"border"`
    widthBorder  string  `json:"widthBorder"`
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите понять json в GO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/303008/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-go)

Comment: Имена полей структуры должны быть с большой буквы. Иначе json, как и любой другой декодер их не будет учитывать.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/hoyU-U-kByV

Comment: Брать указатель `, &p)` не нужно, т.к.  `p` уже хранит указатель.

Comment: Ну там строки ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если float приходит вам в виде текста т.е. в кавычках, то надо в аннотации поля добавить ",string" чтобы Unmarshaller понял, что еще нужно преобразовать:
https://play.golang.org/p/4p_-uudYlpJ

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Point struct {
    X            float64 `json:"x"`
    Y            float64 `json:"y"`
    Speed        float64 `json:"speed,string"`
    SpeedMax     float64 `json:"speedMaxs,string"`
    Acceleration float64 `json:"acceleration,string"`
    Radius       float64 `json:"radius,string"`
    Friction     float64 `json:"friction,string"`
    Color        string  `json:"color"`
    Border       string  `json:"border"`
    WidthBorder  string  `json:"widthBorder"`
}

func main() {

    const in = `{"x":554,"y":236,"speed":"1","radius":"6","speedMax":"5","acceleration":"4","friction":"0.01","color":"#ffffff","border":"#000000","widthBorder":"3"}`

    p := &Point{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("err json:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", p)
}
```

Обратите внимание как по разному закодированы и описаны x,y и остальные поля.